# Can I add an email to my local Notes database using the Lotus Notes API?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm sure I read that it was possible to take an email in RFC 822 format (just the usual raw source format) and add it as a new document into a local NSF database. But I can't seem to find anything in the API that supports this.

I want to bypass a Domino server and POP/IMAP servers and just add the email directly to the inbox.

I need to support Notes 6.5 and up.

I've seen an [example (in VB)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21098323) of sending an email that involves creating a NotesDocument object and setting its properties, as a workaround I could potentially set each of the properties and then use PutInFolder or something similar, but I'd really rather get the email as-is from the raw source.

Is anyone aware of a method in the API that supports importing in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any API call that will transform the raw source of an email into a Notes document.  It doesn't seem likely that IBM would provide such an API given that they have the Domino Server to handle such a thing.  (Side note) In my experience the Notes API doesn't contain any more than the bare minimum it needs to get a job done (and often it is lacking!)

As you saw in the example you can do the transformation yourself using C# and then create the Notes Document via the Lotus Notes API.  An email in Lotus Notes is nothing more than a NotesDocument object with particular properties set.  Theoretically you can set all those properties via the API, or at least enough of them to make the document look/act like a typical email in Notes.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'll give the NotesDocument approach a try and see if I can copy *everything* from the original email.